# Power Sets and Recursive Definition

Tags: set-theory, recurrence-relations, relations

Let $R$ be a relation on $P(A) \times P(A)$, where $P(A)$ is a powerset of a set $A$. Define relation $R$ by recursive form so that $R$ is identical to an operator $\subset$ on $P(A) \times P(A)$.

For the base cases, it will obviously satisfy $(\emptyset, \emptyset) \in R$. However, regarding the recursive steps, it seems a little bit vague on how the recursive steps should be proceeded to obtain the subset properties? Are there any tricks to solve the remaining step?

Comment: Defining something by recursion will usually indicate that there is a certain degree of well-foundedness involved in the definition. The $\subseteq$ relation is well-founded on $\mathcal P(A)$ if and only if $A$ is finite. So you can't quite do that.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Could you elaborate on what you mean by "well-foundedness?" I guess it is totally possible to indicate recursive steps using some well-notation of power sets or relation

Comment: A relation is well-founded if and only if in every non-empty set there is a minimal, and assuming ZFC, if and only if there are no infinite decreasing sequences. Your recursion will only be able to deal with inclusion of finite subsets, not with the whole power set.